# Amazon SNS performance

Tags: performance, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

We are working on a system were we will need to send push notifications to thousands of phones. We have set this up using Amazon SNS. We will be sending individual messages to each phone so we are sending direct to SNS Endpoint ARNs rather that Topic ARNs.

We are currently wondering about the performance of this system. I've not been able to find anything on the net talking about how many messages can be sent to SNS. For example, if I need to send 25,000 messages to 25,000 SNS end points, how fast can I send them? Seconds, minutes, hours?

I know there is a lot of things that can impact this, but I'm trying to find some indicative numbers so we can work out how simple or complex we might need to make the software doing the sending and hopefully avoid over-engineering our solutions.

Thanks for any info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okies. Don't worry. I've run a test where I wrapped a loop around the send function and sent myself 25,000 push notifications. Had to shut my phone down, but the end result was around 13 sends per second or approximately 30 minutes to send 25,000. Not bad given the variables of network latency etc and enough to indicate to use the sorts of architectures we will need to add to the software.

Comment: By parallel processing with some combination of multiple processes, multiple threads, non-blocking event driven async I/O... you should be able to deliver 25,000 in a matter of seconds, not minutes.  The round trip time is the killer when you're doing them sequentially.  You're not really waiting on anything related to the actual capabilities of the service.